# python 2 web server local host error. The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain"

Tags: python, content-type, simplehttpserver

(First time)
I used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` using python 2.7.15 to generate a web server for my simple JavaScript game (still learning), but it seems that it has some error, which makes the canvas of my HTML file wont show.

The JavaScript works totally fine in my GitHub page, but it won't show in local web server. https://jcloh98.github.io/jsgame/simplegame2.html

All the codes are exactly the same as the website. That's all the code I used.

This is the error showed in the console log.

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

https://jcloh98.github.io/jsgame/simplegame2.html

It is expected to show a black canvas with a aqua paddle at the bottom of the canvas, like https://jcloh98.github.io/jsgame/simplegame2.html

Comment: It means that your python web server is sending "text/plain" as the content type for your javascript files, while it should be "application/javascript".

Comment: Hi, may I know how can I change from "text/plain" to "application/javascript"?

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map). For customising, see [here](https://2ality.com/2014/06/simple-http-server.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`, create a .py file named "localhost.py" and run the .py file in the same directory of the webpage.

localhost.py force the file with extension ".js" has "application/javascript" as the content type.

**localhost.py**

```
#Use to create local host
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.extensions_map.update({
    ".js": "application/javascript",
});

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "Serving at port", PORT
print(Handler.extensions_map[".js"])
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Thanks Bergi for helping me to solve this problem out.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it for me.